# How to pass user credentials to gravitee in body request and not as query param

Tags: api, oauth, gravitee

Im trying to authenticate an user in Gravitee AM using OAuth, is the step to get the access token... but i notice that the credentials are passed as query param and not in the body request (as may to be for me... i think), is configuration needed to change this or is an best practice (if Yes, can help me showing the source of the declarative).

the definiton of how to authenticate:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://GRAVITEEIO-AM-GATEWAY-HOST/:securityDomainPath/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=:clientId&client_secret=:clientSecret&username=:username&password=:password&scope=read' \
```

[source](https://docs.gravitee.io/am/2.x/am_quickstart_authenticate_users.html#create_an_identity_provider):

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. Support for public oauth client will be provided in GRavitee.io 3.x (april 2020).
Already available as part of branch, we're currently reviewing it: see https://github.com/gravitee-io/graviteeio-access-management/pull/707.

Regards,